# Ckeditor 5 file uploading adapter error

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor classic 5, and i'm trying to upload images in it. I downloaded php lib Ckfinder3 php connector, set config.

When i'm trying to load image i have a massage: `Cannot upload file *filename*.`

Interesting moment, that they are fisically loaded on server: i can view it in directory, that set in my config file and this files are correct:

```
/var/www/projectfiles/downloadfiles/
```

The next step i'm check permission and groups: it's www-data 0777.

What can be a reason? Can you give some advice or solution?

Thanks!

UPD: init function

```
ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#material_preview' ), {
                ckfinder: {
                    uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/connector/?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
                }

            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
```

php config:

```
$config['authentication'] = function () {
    return true;
};

$config['backends']['default'] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => 'http://files.project.com/downloadfiles/',
    'root'         => '/var/www/projectfiles/downloadfiles/',
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0777,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it!

The connector path is valid. The problem was in cache folder's permisson  in laravel. Be glad if it helps you.

Comment: How did you set the permission for cache folder ? Can you explain ? @segio

Answer (score 0):

The connector path looks invalid. For PHP it should be something like:
'/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files'
Please have a look at CKEditor integration examples in CKFinder demo: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/demo/ckfinder3/samples/ckeditor.html